# How can I get the asymptotic complexity of this code?

Tags: python, recursion

I'm tried to get this complexity O(n).
all steps before recurrence equal steps*O(n) + recurrence T(n)= O(n).

```
lis = []
class Solution:

    def isHappy(self, n: int) -> bool:
        numbers_list = [int(num)**2 for num in str(n)]#O(n)
        numbers_sum = sum(numbers_list)#O(n)
        if numbers_sum == 1:#O(1)
            lis.clear()#O(n)
            return True#O(1)
        if numbers_sum  in lis:#O(n)
            lis.clear()#O(n)
            return False#O(1)
        lis.append(numbers_sum)#O(n)
        return self.isHappy(numbers_sum)#O(n)
```

Comment: What steps do you say are O(1) here? I see a lot of O(N) steps...

Comment: Not sure of complexity since it depends upon how many cycles you have to go through to detect if number is happy.  But, it would be faster if you use a set rather than a list to keep track of the seen numbers.  A set lookup is O(1) while list is O(N)  Also unclear why you're using a class (i.e. Solution) and a global variable (i.e. lis).

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I commited it, mostly all steps O(n) is the worst case O(n)?

Comment: To my understanding, it is. You can read more [here](https://yourbasic.org/algorithms/time-complexity-recursive-functions/) to improve your understanding of algorithmic complexities